# Android Studio/Gradle Project Cleans and Builds but Fails to Debug

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I just migrated an android project from an IntelliJ/Maven setup to an Android Studio/Gradle setup. I can clean it and build it okay, but when I try to debug it, I get the following error. I've looked at a couple of answers here on SO and elsewhere and it seems this problem can be caused by a variety of issues. I am a Gradle beginner but I feel confident that I've ruled out some of those, such as repeated dependencies and busting the 65K method limit (my project is not that big yet and I am not referencing that many/large libraries). I'll appreciate if anyone is able to point me in the right direction.

NB: I should also not that there are 2 jar files in the lib directory.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps780Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","position":{},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lke/co/hoji/BuildConfig;","position":{},"original":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lke/co/hoji/BuildConfig;"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)"}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.79 secs
```

Here's my build file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ke.co.hoji.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. One of the files in the libs directory should have been packaged as an "aar" instead of a "jar" file since it is an Android library. I did that and added the line `compile 'ke.co.hoji:file-name:1.0@aar'` to the build file and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Main Problem is this line

`Multiple dex files define BuildConfig`

First try removing AppCompatLibrary from above location or from `libs` folder

This error occur because of when there are two same libraries exist in a single projects dependencies.